# how to put space between checkbox and image in treeview control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I'm using a treeviewcontrol along with an imagelist and setting its showCheckbox property to `true`. My problem is, checkbox get sticked with the image and doesn't look good. I want to put some space in between checkbox and images.

Comment: Which technology are you talking about: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET ...?

Comment: Is it a windows or web application ?